# Determine scroll move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day. I got an HTML page which is small and has no scroll bar. However i need to determine when and what direction scroller was moved. So i need to determine scroll button on my mouse is moving.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery Mousewheel plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel). Then you can simply bind an event to any element to check if the wheel was used while the mouse was over it.

```
$('body').mousewheel(function(delta){
    // Do stuff
});
```

Note that it's not too user friendly to not have a scrollbar and rely only on the mousewheel. There are other ways people expect to be able to scroll, like the arrow keys for example.